# Django - Getting value from F expression

Tags: python, django, query-expressions

I believe this should be quite easy but it presented some challenge and no advice has came up googling.

I have a django model like this:
`Affiliate -> Account`
where account has a `balance` attribute which keeps track of the account balance. Since it can be modified concurrently, I use an **F() expression** to modify it.

The thing is... in a given test I am trying to compare `affiliate.account.balance` against the expected value `-1.00` (a Decimal value), but it differs, since de F expression was not resolved:

```
First differing element 12: # (yes... I'm comparing it within an array)
Decimal('-1')
<CombinedExpression: F(balance) - Value(1.00)>
```

I use the F expression  like this:

```
def charge(self, **kwargs):
    amount = kwargs.get('amount')
    self.balance = F('balance') + amount
    self.save()
```

Some (maybe) important info:

```
$ python3 -m django --version
1.10.5
```

I've tried

```
affiliate.account.balance.value()
affiliate.account.balance.getValue()
str(affiliate.account.balance)
repr(affiliate.account.balance)
Decimal(affiliate.account.balance)
```

but none of those have the expected effect...

So... How do I get a successful test when I assert

```
self.assertEquals(Decimal(-1.00), affiliate.account.balance)
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Account model

```
class Account(models.Model):
    affiliate = models.OneToOneField(Affiliate, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.DecimalField(_('Balance'), max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal(0.00))
```

Comment: How did you declare your `balance` field on your `Account` model ?

Comment: Will you please post the code for your Account model? It will make answering this question much easier.

Comment: There it goes. I didn't post it straight away cos' I thought it was trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you getting your `account`? You might just need to refresh your reference to the database after the object was updated. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database

so something like..

```
prevBal = account.balance
...charge({amount:...})
account.refresh_from_db()
newBal = account.balance
```

Though honestly I'm still really confused about your setup even after the update.

As far as accessing the `Decimal` value and verifying it in a test.. `accounts.balance` should return the decimal value. Use `isinstance` to verify the type is a `Decimal`. From there what you tried looks about right, as you're just comparing a decimal value to a decimal value. I don't see what this should have to do with using `F`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Nick! You are right! Since I had this referenced model `Affiliate -> Account`, and the balance attribute was in `Account`,
after doing `affiliate.refresh_from_db()`, the balance attribute was not refreshed, but doing `affiliate.account.refresh_from_db()`
did the trick good enough...